# Add foreign key using hibernate and jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Those are my classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="assessment")
public class AssesmentProperties {

  @Id
  @Column(name="AssessmentId")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long AssessmentId;

  @Column(unique=true,nullable=false)
  private String AssessmentName;

  private String AssessmentLevel;
  private String  Specialization;
  private int time;
  private String keywords;
  private int NoOfSections;

  //getters and setters
}


@Embeddable
public class SettingsPrimary implements Serializable {

  private Long AssessmentId;

  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long Section;

 //getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name="section")
public class SectionProperties {

  @EmbeddedId
  private SettingsPrimary PrimaryKey;

  private String SectionType;
  private int Weightage;
  private int time;
  private int NoOfQuestions;

  //getters and setters
}
```

In the table `section` I need to create `assessment_id` as FK to `assessment` table and set cascade on delete. I have tried to do it with different ways but without success.

Comment: Create an attribute of type `AssesmentProperties`? You can set the cascade in the `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToOne` annotation using `cascade=`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="section")
public class SectionProperties {

  @Id
  private Long PrimaryKey;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "assessment_id", referencedColumnName="AssessmentId")
  private AssesmentProperties AssesmentProperties;

  private String SectionType;
  private int Weightage;
  private int time;
  private int NoOfQuestions;

  //getters and setters
}
```

I changed the SectionProperties id to a `Long` and mapped the AssessmentProprties into a ManytoOne prop.
This way, always that a AssessmentProperties binded to a Section will be deleted, the associated SectionProperties will too.